# Fed up trying to install android source behind http_proxy

Tags: android, proxy

I am trying to download android sources. I have to access internet via proxy server. Therefore, I followed the following steps, however always failing:
Downloaded a tool  corkscrew  from http://www.agroman.net/corkscrew/

```
tar zxvf  corkscrew-2.0.tar.gz
cd corkscrew-2.0
./configure
make
cp corkscrew ~/bin
```

Created a  shell script named 'git-proxy' in ~/bin, with following
content:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec ~/bin/corkscrew <proxy name> <proxy port> $*
//mine is: exec ~/bin/corkscrew proxy.company.com 3128 $*
```

and then did:

```
git config --global core.gitproxy '~/bin/git-proxy'
```

Everything seems ok. I have a "repo" in my ~/bin directory. I just rejoice.
And then the problem starts when I type:

```
repo init --trace -u http://android.git.kernel.org/platform/manifest.git -b eclair
```

This is the error I keep getting:

```
/home/**/bin/repo: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
/home/**/bin/repo: line 2: `<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">'
```

Any ideas??

I have also set the environment variable http_proxy as: http://proxy.company.com:3128/

Please help!!

Comment: I tried for countless hours and failed miserably. If you succeed on your quest please let me know and I'll forever worship You The magnificent proxy God!

Comment: I am already going crazy. No clue at all :( :(

Comment: Hey jucas, I think I found it. When you do the curl step and get a repo. The one you get is a wrong one. The md5sum repo command will show you that it is not the one mentioned in the net. What you should do is get the right "repo" from the net. Here is the link! https://docs.google.com/uc?id=0B76d_EyUt5JwNDU5NzFiNzMtYWQ1NC00ZmNlLThiNjQtY2M1NTM3MDQzMzBi&export=download&hl=en_US

Comment: grr... guess this repo script should be changed..Now my error msg reads:Getting repo ...
   from http://android.git.kernel.org/tools/repo.git
error: Failed connect to android.git.kernel.org:8080; Connection timed out while accessing http://android.git.kernel.org/tools/repo.git/info/refs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with proxy, kernel.org got hacked, Google asked to take Android out of the repository for a while...

Here's a way people say it's working:
http://php.webtutor.pl/en/2011/09/05/kernel-org-hacked-how-to-get-android-repo/

Answer (score 0):

Use the global setting file of git for setting the $http_proxy and $HTTP_PROXY properties e.g.

1. sets up the http_proxy Environment variable. To do this, simply do:
   export http_proxy=http://someuser:somepassword@proxy_ip:proxy_port"

Check this for more information:
[using GIT behind proxy](http://roshansingh.wordpress.com/2008/08/29/using-git-behind-proxy/)

Comment: could you explain this a bit with an example? Bcos this is what I tried. I dint succeed :(